# Why some politicians not reducing corruption even after they earned for their 100 generations?

Tags: india, corruption

I am from **South India**. I am always voting to politicians with the hope of they will *take care of people* after they win.
Generally, politicians are earning money by involving in corruption, In some of which earned thousands of crores ( Ex: [Karunanidhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Karunanidhi#Controversies) family from Tamilnadu) which will come for 100's of their upcoming generation even if they spend lavishly.

As a poor voter, I expect the politicians to **reduce their level of corruption** at least after they earned certain money.

*At least after that point* they should think about people who voted them.

But I see even this is **not** happening.

**What drives them to earn more and more?** Don't they realize they have much more than enough?

Or

**Are they that much selfish ?**

Comment: I think a proper answer requires an entire book and that will not be able to find a definitive answer. A similar question was asked many many time where I live (Romania), one of the most corrupt country within the European Union and I think important aspects are the culture and the education. These people simply do not know how to behave differently and they follow a recipe that has proved to work for generations. One possible way to break this vicious circle is to vote for politicians that see a way with less corruption.

Comment: Thanks Alexei, I am eager to know the intentions behind this behavior than looking for a solution, especially in this question. I am thinking like If I earn 1 crore ( 10 million) per day, how I am going to spend it? Whatever I earn beyond that is waste, right? .Why this don't pop in politician's minds?

Comment: It is not only about the money, it is also about the power. Actually it is mostly the power, since they do not just pile up this money, but it is mostly in form of land, factories, companies etc. This is not waste since other people benefit when working in these factories and companies, but the bad thing is that very large resources are concentrated in only a few hands.

Comment: If they end corruption what will happen to their ill gotten gains? A lot of the corrupt are afraid that they will lose everything.

Comment: I said __they are not reduced__ , Instead of taking 70% of the allocated money to themselves, why don't they take 30-40% **atleast after** they earned certain money?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more a question about psychology instead of politics. The point here is the peer comparison.
When you have some status in the society, you compare yourself with your peers, that gives you an idea of your social value. But when you get more money or power (more status), you start to compare yourself with people of higher status as well. Hence, you'll never feel satisfied, because your threshold to measure yourself is always changing. There's always a new challenge, a new goal to reach.
If you don't have your own house, then you compare yourself with people that also don't have a house. But after you buy your own house, you'll start to pay attention towards people that is owner of a house as well.

You see politicians from your own threshold, that's why their behaviour is absurd. But for people on their same level of power, that's perfectly fine.

They won't ever feel is enough.